# Android TableLayout inserting vertical rows

Tags: android, eclipse, html, tablelayout

I've created 5 rows in a TableLayout. I want to merge one item from that row with the one below it, something like this:
 [image: screenshot].
I want to do that programmatically. Is that possible and what is the best approach for this?

Comment: thx for the edit Sam. Now I was thinking how to do that the right way. Maybe in a few linearLayouts put some textviews, every textview should be clickable so I can edit their settings and return to the previous view with the edited textviews.

Comment: Anyone? Just an idea or a little explanation if I can do something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research, I programmatically add textviews in 5 linearLayouts. Every textview have his own onClick method and tag. In database, I put some values (height, width, etc) and tag value. In onCreate method, first grab all the date from database for one linearLayout and with cursor iterate over every textview if there is the one that need to be transformed. If that textview has to be larger in height, you set atribute android:visibility="gone" to the textviews below him. I leave the rest to your programming logic.